# How to start git-daemon at boot?

Tags: git, systemd, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I've created scripts to control starting, stopping, etc. of my git-daemon on Fedora28.  I'm now attempting to link these scripts to a systemd service so git-daemon will be available after reboot.

The primary script (gitT) is...

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  'start')
    echo "Starting git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/start.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'stop')
    echo "Stopping git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/stop.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'restart')
    echo "Bouncing git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/bounce.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'status')
    echo "Status of git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/status.sh
    ;;
  *)
    echo "`basename $0`: usage: `basename $0` { stop | start | restart | status }"
    ;;
esac
```

Secondary scripts are...

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "---------------------"
/usr/bin/git daemon --export-all --enable=receive-pack --verbose --pid-file=/home/git/git-daemon.pid --base-path=/home/git/repos >> /home/git/git-daemon.out 2>> /home/git/git-daemon.err &
echo "---------------------"
echo "STARTED at `date`"
```

stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "---------------------"
pkill -F /home/git/git-daemon.pid
echo "---------------------"
echo "STOPPED at `date`"
```

bounce.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "====================="
/home/git/scripts/stop.sh
echo "====================="
sleep 5
echo "====================="
/home/git/scripts/start.sh
echo "====================="
echo "BOUNCED"
```

and status.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "====================="
ps -x --forest
echo "====================="
```

Finally I created a service file (git-daemon.service)...

```
[Unit]
Description=Git Daemon
Documentation=man:git-daemon(1)
ConditionPathExists=/home/git/repos

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/git/gitT start
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/git/gitT stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=git
Group=git

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I set it up with these commands...

```
cp /home/git/git-daemon.service /etc/systemd/system
systemctl enable git-daemon.service
```

Now if I run `gitT start` as the git user, everything starts fine.  But it I run `systemctl start git-daemon` as root, this is the error...

```
fatal: base-path '/home/git/repos' does not exist or is not a directory
```

Answer (score 6):

> fatal: base-path '/home/git/repos' does not exist or is not a directory

is caused by

> `ConditionPathExists=/home/git/repos`

Since it thinks that directory does not exist. What is the output of

```
ls -ld /home/git/repos
```

?

When running it manually does the process actually start? or are you just not getting any errors back when you run it manually? Since with the level of scripts you have backgrounding and redirecting output they scripts will run successfully no matter if the underlying commands fails or not. You should check the log files you have created.

---

But why do you have so many files to begin with? You can reduce this all down to a single service file with:

```
[Unit]
Description=Git Daemon
Documentation=man:git-daemon(1)
ConditionPathExists=/home/git/repos

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/git daemon --export-all --enable=receive-pack --verbose --base-path=/home/git/repos
User=git
Group=git

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you can view all logs with `journalctl -xfu git-daemon` and not worry about having to keep track of the PID file.

Comment: The output of `# ls -ld /home/git/repos` is `drwxrwxr-x. 3 git git 4096 May 18 08:10 /home/git/repos`.  And as I stated, everything works if I run it from the git user.  Only if I run it from root with systemctl does if fail.